# TSQL: Trying to convert Cursor approach to recursive CTE, get more rows than expec

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I don't code in SQL that much, and need to do some fairly tricky cumulative calculations to calculate a fatigue 'score' for employees working shifts, with that score cumulating through time but also adjusted downwards depending on how many hours rest they have had between shifts.

For each row in the table concerned, I have a start time and an end time, and I then calculate the difference, use a function that calculates the fatigue scorefor each hour between these times (with the funciton summing these and returning a total day figure), then calculate a cumulative sum of this fatigue score across days, adjusting it downwards by a sizeable percentage when the person has a decent break.

I have a Cursor approach that works, but I was curious to try out a CTE approach - not because I necessarily think it will be faster, but because I've never done a recursive CTE before and I think that it would make for good learning and perhaps tidier code.

But I'm doing something silly with the CTE...because in the result set I get an ever increasing amount of rows for each day on my test subject. i.e. on day 1 there is 1 row returned, 2 on day 2, 3 on day three, et cetera.

Here's the Cursor approach I have, that works just fine. (It uses CTEs to construct the query that the cursor operates over).

```
DECLARE @EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @Actual_start AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @Actual_end AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @NextShift AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @HoursRest AS INT;
DECLARE @TotalWork_hrs AS INT;
DECLARE @Cumulative AS DECIMAL(5,2);
DECLARE @Cumulative_PREV AS DECIMAL(5,2);
DECLARE @DailyFatigue AS FLOAT;
DECLARE @FatigueDecay AS Decimal(3,2);

DECLARE @MyCursor AS CURSOR;

SET @Cumulative_PREV = 0;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results;
CREATE TABLE #Results(
    EmployeeID NVARCHAR(8)
    , Actual_start DATETIME
    , Actual_end DATETIME
    , NextShift DATETIME
    , HoursRest INT
    , TotalWork_hrs INT
    , DailyFatigue FLOAT
    , FatigueDecay DECIMAL(3,2)
    , Cumulative FLOAT
    );


SET @MyCursor  = CURSOR FOR

    WITH CTE_1 AS
    (SELECT  
            [EmployeeId]
            ,[Actual_start]
            ,[Actual_end]
            ,LEAD([Actual_start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeId] ORDER BY [EmployeeId], [Actual_start]) AS 'NextShift'
            ,[TotalWork_hrs]
            ,[Shift_Order]

        FROM [HRBI].[dbo].[WFTM_Fatigue_Current]
        WHERE 
            [Workday] = 'WD'
            AND [Actual_start]> DATEADD(dd,-90,GETDATE())
            AND [EmployeeId] = '00110838')

, CTE_2 AS
    (SELECT     
        [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        , CONVERT(INT,COALESCE([NextShift],[Actual_end])-[Actual_end])*24 AS [HoursRest]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[Shift_Order]
    FROM CTE_1)

, CTE_3  AS
    (SELECT
        [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        ,[HoursRest]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[Shift_Order]
        ,dbo.ufn_GetDailyFatigue([Actual_start], [Actual_end]) AS [DailyFatigue]
        , CASE 
            WHEN [HoursRest] > 16 THEN 1-POWER(0.50, ((HoursRest+8)/24-1) )
          ELSE 0
          END  AS [FatigueDecay]
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EmployeeId], [Actual_start]) AS ROW#
    FROM CTE_2 )

SELECT [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        ,[HoursRest]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[DailyFatigue]
        ,[FatigueDecay] 
FROM CTE_3


OPEN @MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @EmployeeId, @Actual_start, @Actual_end,  @NextShift, @HoursRest,  @TotalWork_hrs, @DailyFatigue, @FatigueDecay;


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SET @Cumulative = @TotalWork_hrs + @Cumulative_PREV * (1-@FatigueDecay);
 SET @Cumulative_PREV = @Cumulative;
 INSERT INTO #Results ([EmployeeID], [Actual_start],[Actual_end], [NextShift], [HoursRest], [TotalWork_hrs], [DailyFatigue], [FatigueDecay], [Cumulative])  
 VALUES(@EmployeeId, @Actual_start, @Actual_end,  @NextShift, @HoursRest,  @TotalWork_hrs, @DailyFatigue, @FatigueDecay, @Cumulative)
 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @EmployeeId, @Actual_start, @Actual_end,  @NextShift, @HoursRest,  @TotalWork_hrs, @DailyFatigue, @FatigueDecay;
END

CLOSE @MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;

SELECT * FROM #Results
ORDER BY EmployeeID, Actual_start
```

And it returns exactly what I want. Notice the highlighting: This is an example when the staff member has had a decent break between the previous shift and this shift and so their cumulative score has been adjusted down.

[image]

And here's my attempt using a recursive CTE, which only differs in that it simply adds one more CTE to the end of the others, and doesn't have any of the now redundant CURSOR stuff:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS
    (SELECT  
            [EmployeeId]
            ,[Actual_start]
            ,[Actual_end]
            ,LEAD([Actual_start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeId] ORDER BY [EmployeeId], [Actual_start]) AS 'NextShift'
            ,[TotalWork_hrs]
            ,[Shift_Order]
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeId] ORDER BY [EmployeeId], [Actual_start]) AS ROW#

        FROM [HRBI].[dbo].[WFTM_Fatigue_Current]
        WHERE 
            [Workday] = 'WD'
            AND [Actual_start]> DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE())
            AND [EmployeeId] = '00110838')

, CTE_2 AS
    (SELECT     
        [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[Shift_Order]
        ,[ROW#]
        , CONVERT(INT,COALESCE([NextShift],[Actual_end])-[Actual_end])*24 AS [HoursRest]
    FROM CTE_1)

, CTE_3  AS
    (SELECT
        [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[Shift_Order]
        ,[ROW#]
        ,[HoursRest]
        ,dbo.ufn_GetDailyFatigue([Actual_start], [Actual_end]) AS [Fatigue]
        , CASE 
            WHEN [HoursRest] > 16 THEN 1-POWER(0.50, ((HoursRest+8)/24-1) )
          ELSE 0
          END  AS [FatigueDecay]

    FROM CTE_2 ), 

 CTE_4  AS
    (SELECT [EmployeeId]
        ,[Actual_start]
        ,[Actual_end]
        ,[NextShift]
        ,[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,[Shift_Order]
        ,[ROW#]
        ,[HoursRest]
        ,[Fatigue]
        ,[FatigueDecay]
        ,[Cumulative] = [Fatigue]


    FROM CTE_3

    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
        new.[EmployeeId]
        ,new.[Actual_start]
        ,new.[Actual_end]
        ,new.[NextShift]
        ,new.[TotalWork_hrs]
        ,new.[Shift_Order]
        ,new.[ROW#]
        ,new.[HoursRest]
        ,new.[Fatigue]
        ,new.[FatigueDecay]
        ,[Cumulative] = new.[Fatigue] + base.Cumulative*new.FatigueDecay

    FROM CTE_3 new

    INNER JOIN CTE_4 base
    ON base.EmployeeId = new.EmployeeId 
    AND new.ROW# = base.ROW# + 1 
    )


SELECT  * FROM CTE_4
ORDER BY Actual_start

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

...and as per the below screenshot, I have a ROW# column in there that shows the amount of rows returned keeps multiplying for some reason, and my cumulative calculations aren't working

[image]

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Do you really expect people to debug that massive wall of code for you, without even having sample data?  Please create a [mcve] including sample data as DDL+DML and desired results. Emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. I'm very wet behind the ears when it comes to SQL, to the point that I had to google DDL and DML to see what they meant. And then in the process of making a small table of sample data I saw what I had missed initially.  Things are a little different in the Excel/VBA-focused SO niche I inhabit, where I'm often answering questions about the VBA object model often with no access to sample data, but a question that is answerable because of the error that the user has. But that's a different kettle of fish entirely.

Comment: First, it's great you could answer your own question! That is one of  the main reasons why you should create a [mcve]. Second, You (well, everyone) should read and embrace  the [Rubber Duck Problem Solving/](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I finally see what I've done. Forgot to limit the initial CTE to just one row i.e. missing a "WHERE ROW# = 1" from the initial select in CTE_4